# Website Bookmark/ Shortcut Icon for Android Help. Cant get passed standard ribbon icon

Tags: android, mobile, icons, shortcut, bookmarks

I have a website with a mobile version and I am trying to get it so that when someone chooses to Bookmark the website or 'Add to home screen' it will save an Icon to the home screen. I have an Android Samsung Galaxy S3 and no matter what I try I cannot get it to use the icon instead of the standard ribbon with tiny preview in the middle.

**Currently..The below code will get it to display the standard ribbon with tiny preview of favicon image but will not display the entire icon:**

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.mydomain.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.mydomain.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

**I have also tried this code as well which only yields the standard ribbon icon when I add the bookmark to my homescreen. Not even a tiny preview like above:**

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://www.mydomain.com/customicon.ico"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="http://www.mydomain.com/customicon.ico"/>
```

**Note:** I have also tried 1) Placing the icon files in the root. 2) Naming the filename to apple-touch-icon-precomposed.ico. 3) Icon is 57x57 and under 40 kb.

I know there is some way to accomplish this because I tested a couple of websites like AOL, and eBay and both save to my home screen with a normal sized icon that appears like an app.

If anyone has run into the same problem and found a solution that works please let me know. I am stumped!

Comment: did you tried any solution for ***Android phone***?

Answer (score 0):

The entire issue was because the website was .htaccess password protected for testing purposes during design and development. All I had to do was move the folder that contained all icons outside of the password protected directory!

The following code is what I used and is now working:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="http://m.mydomain.com/touch-icon-ipad-retina.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="http://m.mydomain.com/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="http://m.mydomain.com/touch-icon-ipad.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://m.mydomain.com/touch-icon-iphone.png" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
```