# Save site as a mobile shortcut android

Tags: javascript, android, html

I spent a lot of time to search for solution but without result.

I check this topics :

[Website Bookmark/ Shortcut Icon for Android Help. Cant get passed standard ribbon icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588250/website-bookmark-shortcut-icon-for-android-help-cant-get-passed-standard-ribbo)

Whick is very nice ,but here user must click on bookmark.That`s not what i need. May be button,or automatic script that prompt user for this and created automaticaly.For example something like this :

http://socialmedia.biz/2012/02/21/encourage-visitors-to-save-your-site-as-a-mobile-shortcut/

But it`s work only on Apple devices .. What im looking for is a similar solution for android.

Is this possible at all?

May be the only solution is to create simple app that act like a shortcut to my web page?
The page that is talking about has a mobile version ..

Comment: It isn't that easy to create a "webapp" shortcut on Android. However you can use PhoneGap to transform your webpages into a real Android/iOS/... app.

Comment: Yes.. this is a option, but we already developed mobile web site.. And now client want Icon ..

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked here [for Chrome]? https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/installtohomescreen

> May be the only solution is to create simple app that act like a shortcut to my web page? The page that is talking about has a mobile version ..

If this is "allowed" and doesn't go against too many guidelines, this might be your only option. Basically you'd want to create a one Activity application and all it does is call the default Intent for your web page. This should push the user into the default Browser.

You could put the app in the Google Play store and link to it from the site or a script. I'd call the app something like "SITE_NAME Web Shortcut" and make it clear in the description that the only purpose is to launch the browser -- as previously mentioned this doesnt "feel" like something that should be in an app store, and if users think they're getting something extra you'll definitely get bad reviews.

(I'd also make the Activity with @style/Theme.Transparent)

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that Chrome has changed the way that installs web apps.

Here are the details: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/a2hs-updates

There is an install criteria now:

- The web app is not already installed
- Meets a user engagement heuristic
- Be served over HTTPS
- Includes a Web App Manifest that includes:
- - short_name or name
- - icons - must include a 192px and a 512px icon
- - start_url
- - display - must be one of fullscreen, standalone, or minimal-ui
- - prefer_related_applications must not be present, or be false
    -Registers a service worker with a fetch handler